# How to SUM UP Time values of Similar Employees in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have three tables

- **Employee**: `EmployeeID, EmployeeName`
- **EmployeeTimeIn** : `EID, Time_In, Date_Ref, State_Flag, HoursConsumed`
- **EmployeeTimeOut** : `EID, Time_Out, Date_Ref, State_Flag`

I have attached image of these tables containing sample data.

I need to write a query which will list all employees with id, name, and total time they consumed. For that purpose i need to sum up time values of each employee. I wrote this query which lists all employees which are listed in timein and timeout tables:

```
select e.EmployeeID, e.EmployeeName, e1.HoursConsumed
from EmployeeTimeIn as e1, Employee as e
where e1.EID = e.EmployeeID;
```

I want to do something like this:

```
select e.EmployeeID, e.EmployeeName, SUM(e1.HoursConsumed)
from EmployeeTimeIn as e1, Employee as e
where e1.EID = e.EmployeeID;
```

`HoursConsumed` is a time field. Any ideas?

[image: Employee Tables]

Comment: If you add `GROUP BY  e.EmployeeID, e.EmployeeName` doesn't it work?

Comment: It showed this error:
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: Have you defined EmployeeName as text or ntext?

Comment: Seems like you are using the wrong datatype for `EmployeeName` then. You should be using for example `varchar(50)` or `nvarchar(50)` not one of the deprecated large object datatypes.

Comment: yes name datatype was text, now i changed it to varchar(50). Now this error shows up:
Operand data type time is invalid for sum operator.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have your grouping fields as varchar() or similar types, you can do something like this...

```
select e.EmployeeID, e.EmployeeName, SUM(DATEDIFF(ns, 0, e1.HoursConsumed))
from EmployeeTimeIn as e1, Employee as e
where e1.EID = e.EmployeeID;
group by e.EmployeeID, e.EmployeeName
```

Depending on the accuracy of what you're summing, you might use a different time unit.  TIME is accurate to 100ns (as default, and at best), so using `ns` maintains absolute accuracy, but become more likely to overflow with large volumes of data :)

If you need to convert it back to a time, you can use something like:

```
DATEADD(ns, SUM(DATEDIFF(ns, 0, e1.HoursConsumed)), 0)
```

Comment: This throws overflow error:
Msg 535, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

Comment: With `NS` you can calculate difference between the timestamps that are just over two seconds apart from each other at most! `MS` might be enough, and judging by the OP's examples, it could even be `S`.

Comment: After a thorough study, I find out that in order to work this out i need to write very complex t-SQL script. So I changed datatype of HoursConsumed to integer and now i can use SUM function.
Thank you for your quick responses.